# When using constructor dependency injection, is it normal for the injector class to become a large list of constructors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, solid-principles

I was not sure if better to ask here, or on GameDev Stack Exchange. I believe it carries over to general programming.

**Context**

- I am using Unity3D and building an Online Multiplayer Game.
- I would like to use Constructor Dependency Injection, so no "magic" reflection to keep things simple and be able to view my dependencies more clearly.
- I would like to have Sub Injector Classes that will resolve dependencies.

For example when I spawn a `Player` into the game world the root `PlayerScript` will be an injector that will resolve all of the players dependencies.

The `Player` will have a service collection and then it will construct each service the player needs to function.

**Problem**

The `Player` injector becomes a large list of constructing the services the player needs. I am trying to use SOLID principles, so by splitting my player services into many smaller services. This might mean having 20-30 services on the player. It just feels wrong to have 20-30 lines of code constructing each services and passing them their dependencies.

This is kind of what it is looking like if it wasn't in Unity3D.

**Outside of Unity Example**

```
        //PlayerMovement
       Services.Add<CharacterController>(new CharacterController(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));

        //PlayerInputs
        Services.Add<UIInputs>(new UIInputs(Inject 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<InventoryInputs>(new InventoryInputs(Inject 1,Inj 2));
        Services.Add<MovementInputs>(new MovementInputs(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<InteractionInputs>(new CrossHair(Inj 1,Inj 2));

        //PlayerInventory
        Services.Add<InventoryStateManager>(new InventoryStateManager(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<PlayerInventory>(new PlayerInventory(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<CursorInventory>(new CursorInventory(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<ActionBarInventory>(new ActionBarInventory(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));

        //PlayerUI
        Services.Add<PlayerUI>(new PlayerUI(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3);
        Services.Add<InventoryViewManager>(new InventoryViewManager(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<PlayerInventoryView>(new PlayerInventoryView(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<CursorInventoryView>(new CursorInventoryView(Inj 1,Inj 2));
        Services.Add<ActionBarInventoryView>(new ActionBarInventoryView(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<StorageInventoryView>(new StorageInventoryView(Inj 1,Inj 2));
        Services.Add<ActionBarSelection>(new ActionBarSelection(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
        Services.Add<CrossHair>(new CrossHair(Inj 1,Inj 2, Inj 3));
```

**Unity Differences**

Only read if interested in how I implemented using Unity.

In unity you cannot construct monobehaviour classes. So instead you have to find all of your dependencies that already exist on the player.

I did that by adding `IService` interface to all Monobehaviours in the Scene. When Player Spawns into the server it will find all `IService`s, and then I will inject the dependencies by calling an initialization function on each service.

**Question**

Is it normal to have a lot of services constructed in one injector class?

Please correct me if I have a misunderstanding here.

Comment: Probably depends a bit on how exactly you define `Service` .. what general code architecture do you use for your application? I would e.g. claim that anything that is a `Service` could be a Non-MonoBehaviour class which is then only consumed by the MonoBehaviour UI components. Then further I would assume that all services are initialized by your central dependency injection simulator (^^) before any UI starts to consume them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally normal that injections constructed in one class, that's actually what it is for. You can easilly control and see your dependencies at single place but you should be aware that if you're services are monobehaviour then probably it is not a service. That class Also called as Context generally and there can be more than one context.

You're current injections aren't services, they are more like views that player see. generally views don't do logic but it is also a must that monobehaviour be inside views like player movement.

You can think that views are unity related things and you clamp unity related things as views. Services are used widely as the game runs and don't have related things to the unity. i.e IAuthService for Steam, Epic games, Xbox etc or SettingsService for different OSs.

Many people names their classes names as PlayerController, UiManager/Service without realazing. What they try to achieve looks like always MVC but in a messy way. What i said is also looks almost identical to MVC(S). I think you should look at MVC(S) architectural pattern and get some inspiration.

There's already a framework that supports MVCS + IoC, it is [Strange](https://strangeioc.github.io/strangeioc/), you should definetly check it.

Comment: I don’t even know if I am labeling those right as Views* as they have logic on all of them they are really the controllers*

With using unity networking libraries almost all of your logic and services have to be mono-behaviors to send RPCs to and from server. 

So I am just trying to handle where you typically inject all the dependencies for each controller. When the server spawns a new player with all of its dependencies need to be resolved. Do you only do this kind of injection with services? If so how do the controllers get their dependencies? I’ll take a look at that library too!Thanks

Comment: A controller should be non-monobehaviour because if you make controllers monobehaviour they are actually becoming both controller and view. you can think a view as a gameobject in a scene it can also do unity logic. what you need an event system, a controller should be executed when something happens like player joins to the game. your context should inject all of your dependencies so you should have something like this, ``IContext.InstanstiateView(go)``. you should bind your controller to the an event like SpawnPlayerController to PlayerJoinedEvent and that controller do it job

Comment: first you need to make a injection container then you should write your mvc framework and use the injection in your framework, just with ioc you can't make that communication. you can call injection class a context but not a mvc context.

Comment: Thank you for this! It answers the questions well, and at least gives me an idea of what I should be looking into. I really appreciate your time and thoughts.

Comment: I forgot to say but there's a simple way to handle services that need gameobject. as you know context handles all the controller,model,view and services, creates them and inject dependencies. so all of the object knows it's context and context also could inject itself into the service, so with that way you can instantiate a gameobject/view for your service via context injection.

Comment: In the context of dependency injection, a service refers to any object which is injected to a client for it to use. So components can also be services, if DI is used to injected them to other objects that depend on them.

Answer (score 0):

That is not unusual. The more you make use of dependency injection, the more you end up pushing the responsibility of object creation upwards, until at some point you reach a "ceiling". This is where you should have your **Composition Root**; the place where you compose the object graph.

In DI circles it's actually a common recommendation, that one should preferably only have a single Composition Root in the entire application.

However, I personally think that in the world of Unity, where scenes and prefabs also offer a powerful way to compose objects together, it can be better to give prefabs and scene objects - or even individual components, actually -  their own little Composition Roots to hold references to local services that should be injected to clients. I see you also ended up doing something similar with your IService-based implementation!

I rolled out my own DI solution for Unity ([Init(args)](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/init-args-200530)) a couple of months back. In it I went with an approach where a separate "Initializer" can be generated for each component, and it takes on the responsibility of injecting all the dependencies to its client component.

While some hardcore DI purists would probably find this sort of multi-composition-root approach objectionable, it does come with a lot of benefits as well.

For example, when working in a team with multiple developers, having only a single Composition Root can result in more merge conflicts, when multiple feature teams end up modifying the object graph in their own branches.

So my recommendation is not to worry **too** much about what is "normal", but focus on actual pain points in your development process and adjust the solutions you are using so as to get rid of these as much as you can :)

Comment: I see scenes as a context or a root(i mean multiple context), with that there's no need to edit scene, everything instantiated from the context solves the merge conflict instead makes no need to edit scene,. if there's something to get edited just editing prefab is becomes very good approach or just the edit the code.

Comment: @Sisus Thank you so much for that explanation, with unity it just seems like a good idea to have like higher level services injected at the main composition root, and have a sub composition root for gameobjects like you mentioned. I will take a look at that asset you mentioned. It seems like it may be what I was looking for a more straightforward approach to DI without all the bloat Zenject brings.